# Mandarin equivalent of 返 in Cantonese? Is it 回?

Tags: translation, equivalent-phrase

In Cantonese, one of the ways 返 is used is to express "return" or "back". What word in Mandarin is the best equivalent to it? Would it be 回?

Here are the examples - not sure if the translation is correct.

Ex. 我要還返本書俾佢 -> 我要还回本书给他 (I need to return a book to him)

Ex. 走之前記住攞返鎖匙 -> 走之前记住拿回钥匙 (before you leave, remember to get your keys)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps it's also better to provide English versions for the examples? Just so that a non-Cantonese speaker can also answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

As a verb particle, the Mandarin equivalent of 返 in Cantonese is indeed 回

俾**返**你一啲好處(C) = 給**回**你一點好處 (M) = give you **back** some benefit

Edit:

- First, the term 還返 is uniquely Cantonese, "我要還返本書俾佢" in Mandarin would just be "我要还本书给他".
- Second, 本 is a classifier without determiner or count word, it  is normal in Cantonese, but in Mandarin, you should not omit the determiner or count word; you should write "我要还(這)本书给他" or "我要还(一)本书给他"
- Finally, you can omit the classifier along with the determiner and write "我要還書俾佢" / "我要还书给他

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just wondering though, is 回 used after the verb? Like for my first example, is "我要还回本书给他" correct or should it be "我要回还本书给他”?

Comment: In this case, the 回 would not be needed, as idiomatic Mandarin requires just 还. The Cantonese verb 還返 just becomes the one verb 還/还 in Mandarin.